# why my django profile update function not wokring?

Tags: html, django

I am only trying to test the default user profile update through UserChangeForm. Just the email field. So below are the code snippet.

views.py

```
@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def editUserProfile(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form = UserProfileUpdateForm(request.POST)
            form.save()
            return redirect('thank_you')
        else:
            messages.error(request, f'Please correct the error below.')
    else:
        form = UserProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
    return render(request, "authenticate\\editProfilePage.html", {'form': form})
```

forms.py

```
class UserProfileUpdateForm(UserChangeForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', )
```

HTML

```
<div class="container h-100">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center h-100">
            <div class="user_card">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <h3 id="form-title">Update Profile</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center form_container">

                    <form method="POST" action="{% url 'editUserProfile' %}">
                        {% csrf_token %}

                        <div class="input-group mb-2">
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-envelope-square"></i></span>
                            </div>
                            {{form.email}}
                        </div>

                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-3 login_container">
                            <input class="btn login_btn" type="update" value="update">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                    {{form.errors}}

    <script>
                        /* Because i didnt set placeholder values in forms.py they will be set here using vanilla Javascript
        //We start indexing at one because CSRF_token is considered and input field
         */

        //Query All input fields
        var form_fields = document.getElementsByTagName('input')
        form_fields[4].placeholder='email';


        for (var field in form_fields){
            form_fields[field].className += ' form-control'
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

In the user profile page, I could see the update button, and when I click on it I am redirected to the edit profile page, and I am also able to see the old email address mentioed in the email field. So far so good.

However, when I replace the old email with new one and click on the "update" button nothing happens. No error, no redirection. Nothing. The page remains there.

Comment: Is `form = UserProfileUpdateForm(request.POST)` above the `form.save()` really necessary?

Comment: I guess that is what is giving the update functionality. Please correct me if I am wrong. I have also seen many posts in and out stackoverflow, and users have this line.

Comment: Seeing as you already called it once, I don't see the need to call it a second time, inside the `form.is_valid` statement.

Comment: ok, let me try to make that change. Will let you know

Comment: Ok, I have removed that was inside the if statement. I guess there are no changes, I still not able to update the email

Answer (score 0):

There were sytax errors in my HTML code, so I re-wrote the entire HTML again. That resolved the issue. Thank you